# Spring Data Neo4j "Hello, World" standalone app

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to write a "Hello, World" with Spring Data Neo4j in a standalone app.  It runs and actually creates the Neo4j database, but my `@Autowired` repo is not being initialized.  I suspect the problem is in my main class, but I don't know what to try.  Unsurprisingly, almost all the Spring tutorials I've found are about web apps.

What am I doing wrong?

config bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "test2")
public class ConfigBean extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/home/kevin/tmp/hello-spring-data-neo4j/";

    public ConfigBean() {
        setBasePackage("test2");
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    }
}
```

node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Foo {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
}
```

repository:

```
public interface FooRepository extends GraphRepository<Foo> { }
```

main class:

```
@Component
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    FooRepository repo;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("repo: " + repo); // null!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test2");
        new Test2().doStuff();
    }
}
```

It logs about 350 lines of output.  These are the last few lines.  I searched for this error message, but the impression I got is that it's unrelated to my problem.

```
20:44:30.630 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
20:44:30.631 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
20:44:30.635 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
repo: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Via the magical "ask a question, find the answer" effect, my main class now looks like this, and the repo is being assigned:

```
@Component
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    FooRepository repo;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("repo: " + repo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test2");
        Test2 test2 = context.getBean(Test2.class);
        test2.doStuff();
    }
}
```