# Crashes related to GraphRepository#findAll() when using AspectJ

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

This line in TopLevelTransaction (neo4j-kernel-2.1.2) throws a `NullPointerException` every time I call `next()` on an iterator obtained via `GraphRepository#findAll()`:

```
protected void markAsRollbackOnly()
{
    try
    {
        transactionManager.getTransaction().setRollbackOnly(); // NPE here
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        throw new TransactionFailureException(
            "Failed to mark transaction as rollback only.", e );
    }
}
```

I found some threads about similar crashes with slightly different stack traces.  The accepted solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111863/spring-data-neo4j-repository-findall-results-in-a-nullpointerexception) is to use "proxy" transaction management, but that seems like a band-aid solution.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616710/spring-transactional-with-aspectj-is-totally-ignored) also mentions "proxy" transaction management and suggests that there might be something wrong with the `@Transactional` annotation when using AspectJ.

Is this legitimately a bug, or have I just set up my project incorrectly?  My code is essentially the same as in my [standalone hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817028/spring-data-neo4j-hello-world-standalone-app), with a slightly more complex main class:

```
@Component
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    FooRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test2");
        Test2 test2 = context.getBean(Test2.class);
        test2.doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        createFoo();
        printFoos();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Foo createFoo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("Derp" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        repo.save(foo);
        System.out.println("saved " + foo.toString());
        return foo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void printFoos() {
        Iterable<Foo> foos = repo.findAll();
        System.out.println("findAll() returned instance of " + foos.getClass().getName());
        Iterator<Foo> iter = foos.iterator();
        System.out.println("iterator is instance of " + iter.getClass().getName());
        if(iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next(); // CRASHES HERE
        }
    }
}
```

I can post my POM if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a bug.  Two or three things are required to make this work, depending on whether you want to use proxy or AspectJ transaction management.

First, transaction management must be enabled.  Since I'm using annotation-based configuration, I did this by annotating my `@Configuration` class with `@EnableTransactionManagement`.  Contrary to the docs, the default mode now seems to be `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ`, not `AdviceMode.PROXY`.

Next, you need to ensure that the Iterator is used within a transaction.  In my example, if I use `AdviceMode.PROXY` the entire bean containing the `@Autowired` repository has to be annotated `@Transactional`.  If I use `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ` I can annotate just the method.  This is because the call to the method using the iterator is a self-call from within the bean, and proxy transaction management cannot intercept and manage internal calls.

Finally, if you're using `AdviceMode.ASPECTJ` you must set up weaving as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718245/how-to-enable-aspectj-compile-time-weaving-with-java-7-and-maven).